# histogram of duplicate id [sql]

Tags: sql, histogram

I have table that each ID appear  many times.
I want to create table that show me how many ID appear one time, how many  appear two times and ets.
for example:

```
value   count
1        123
2        513
3        215
.
.
.
```

value 1 mean that 123 ID apear one time  .  513 ID apear 2 times (513 ID have two rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
 select id,count(id)as count_of_id
 from your_table
 group by id
 having count(id)>1
```

Comment: thats not what I looked for. I edited the exapmle

Comment: I guess, it would be better if you edit your output once more, because now it is confusing: ID is in the column count and count of occurrences in the column value. You can also remove having count(id)>1 from my query to see records that appeared once

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY value
```

Comment: I dont have parameter "value".  value 1 mean apear one time  . for example .  513 ID apear 2 times

Comment: In your example you have a column value and a column count.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select count(id) as value
      ,id as count
from your_table_name
group by id
order by count(id)
```